# HttpGet without Accept Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, webclient

I want to simulate a HttpGet request on my asp.net website. The request should have no Accept-Header. How can I do that using webrequest or webclient in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.  Create a console application and add the Microsoft.Net.Http nuget package.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.example.com").Result;
```